# Why did the price of Turkish on-arrival visas for Australians just rise by 200%?

Tags: visas, budget, turkey, australian-citizens, visas-on-arrival

So I've had to get three visas for Turkey in the last couple of years and each time it cost € 15 / $ 20.

But a few days ago I met some Australian travellers here in Georgia who just came from Turkey and they told me that very recently (June 2012 or just before) the price has tripled, just for us, to € 45 / $ 60!

Can anybody tell me why? Did my government do anything to upset the Turkish government? Might it go back down again soon if some diplomatic faux pas is patched up? Was there some official announcement explaining it or did it just happen silently?

Comment: Such moves are often bilateral. Could it be the case that the Australian government did the same for Turkish citizens or that it imposed more stringent entry requirements on them?

Comment: Yes it could well be - so I'd really like to know so that I can be justly annoyed at my government. But they're not always reciprocal. After the war between Russia and Georgia where I am now, Russia bans Georgian tourists but Georgia doesn't even require visa from Russian tourists to visit. So anything is possible.

Comment: I imagine that it would be fatal for Georgia's tourism industry if the Russians (and their rubles) stopped coming. Also Russian businessmen are very welcome there, although there is an embargo on the Russian side ...

Comment: Hmm maybe but in the almost eight months I've been here there have not been more Russian tourists than from anywhere else... maybe their numbers will jump through the roof in July and August but not so far...

Comment: Loads of Armenians seem to hit Batumi in the summer.

Comment: They're being passive-aggressive about their hate towards Fosters Beer.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen: Yep they're not here yet either but they were when I was here in August/September 2010.

Comment: I have not been able to go back to the official source, but I have found [some interesting figures](http://theyounggeorgians.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/tourism-in-georgia-statistics/). In 2011, the top three groups of visitors in Georgia have been from Azerbaijan, Turkey and Armenia, with a share of 22% each. The fourth group are the Russians, with a share of 9%. I am sure that their importance will increase if you take into account their expenditures.

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this question. We just arrived in Istanbul and as the holders of 2 Australian passports, were asked for 90 Euros for our entry. Everyone else was handing over 15E. We had read that it was 15 Euros each and were a bit surprised and honestly thought there had been a mistake. The officer asked us how much we thought it was and we told him 15 Euros. He then made a big fuss about Australians and how difficult we all were. - it was very embarrassing and I don't think we were being difficult at all. Anyhow, take this sage advice from the Pom at the window next to us who

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the official announcement from the Turkish Ministry of Foreign Affairs: [Avustralya vatandaşlarına sınırda vize ücreti](http://melburn.bk.mfa.gov.tr/ShowAnnouncement.aspx?ID=153386). There's no reason given for the increase.

In the warnings for Turkish citizens travelling to foreign countries, I don't see anything about visa rates for Australia having gone up, whereas there are announcements about changes for other countries.

Comment: Any idea what the last sentence says? Google Translate doesn't help so much with that part.

Comment: Something like "Our citizens are respectfully [being] informed in order to prevent any possible problems at our border posts." I'm not sure why they feel it necessary to announce it to "our [i.e. Turkish] citizens".

Comment: Hopefully there won't be incensed gun-toting Aussies in the visa line while I'm there!

Comment: I'm secretly happy that someone else has to pay as much as Canadians do.

Comment: Canadians also have to pay this much? My informants gave me the impression the change only applied to us.

Comment: Canadians have been paying that much for years. It used to be $20 though.

Comment: I feel your pain )-: But at least I can be happy that we didn't offend Turkey as early as you did d-;

Comment: Did Australia just recognise the Armenian genocide or something? That'd get at least a 200% response out of the Turks!

Answer (score 7):

Diplomatic protocol requires that nobody ever explain the reason for anything directly, but I can only presume it's tit for tat, as Turkish citizens wishing to visit Australia have to fork out A$110 for a tourist visa.  Australia last year announced that much cheaper ETAs (A$20) are [now available for Turkish diplomats and special passport holders](http://www.migrationexpert.com.au/visa/australian_immigration_news/2011/sep/0/508/online_tourist_visa_applications_open_for_chilean_and_turkish_nationals), but specifically excluded ordinary passports.