# Does Turkey no longer offer visa on arrival to Australian passport holders?

Tags: turkey, visas-on-arrival, australian-citizens

I'm an Australian citizen who's been to Turkey several times, starting in 2010, but not for a couple of years now.

Each time I visited, I was able to obtain a visa on arrival at the land border or airport. [(Only the fee changed between my earlier and later visits.)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7844/why-did-the-price-of-turkish-on-arrival-visas-for-australians-just-rise-by-200)

But now a friend who is also an Aussie but living in Germany is asking me about visiting Turkey and tells me Australians must now obtain a visa in advance.

Is my friend correct? Did the rules change or was he given inaccurate advice?

Comment: Speculation: people looking to fight in Syria and Iraq come via Turkey, and they're trying to do something about that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most people from countries that used to get visa on arrival in Turkey now have to apply for an e-visa and are advised to do so before traveling.

[This site has the information on the e-visa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/who-is-eligible-for-e-visa/) and who can apply.
And [this page has the information what kind of visa Australians](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) need to have.

> Australia: Ordinary and official passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey. Ordinary passport holders can obtain three month-multiple entry e-Visas via the website www.evisa.gov.tr.

If you have no chance to apply before arrival, or do not want to do it, you can risk waiting till you arrive, (or your friend of course,) [see this page, go down to the right FAQ](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/) and check your country is in the list.
Australia is on the list.

Comment: [Direct link](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/i-do-not-want-to-apply-for-an-e-visa-can-i-get-a-visa-on-arrival/) to the relevant FAQ.

Comment: FAQ is interesting, it says that if one does not want e-visa, then its possible to apply for visa on arrival. And it also says that ministry website has more information. Ministry website on the other hand says that e-visa has replaced "sticker visa" given on arrival. Go figure. Anyone with personal experience?

Comment: Note that the reason that Germany is not on the list of visa-upon-arrival countries is because German citizens don't need any kind of visa to visit Turkey, just their passport.

Answer (score 4):

According to the webpage of Turkish Ministry of Foreign affairs

"As of April 17, 2013, electronic visa (e-Visa) replaces “sticker visa” which was issued at the border crossings.  Applicants just need to log on to http://www.evisa.gov.tr, provide the requested information, (after the application is approved) make online payment and download their e-Visa."

http://www.mfa.gov.tr/consular-info.en.mfa